# What causes the kernel oops in the "make -j4" process

Tags: linux, gcc, linux-kernel, arm

I am using an embedded board with 4 armv8 cores.(xilinx zynqmp)

I found that using make -j4 to compile software will appear kernel oops.

The stack of oops is almost the same,but the type of oops is different,i have seen three types:

- undefined instrction
- unable to handle kernel paging request
- NULL pointer access

I don't understand why compile will cause kernel oops. Does the make/gcc program interact with the kernel? Please help analyze what causes this problem?

Thanks.

an oops message：

```
[  240.633378] Internal error: undefined instruction: 0 [#1] SMP
[  240.633383] Unable to handle kernel paging request at virtual address ffffff8016df6480
[  240.633386] Unable to handle kernel paging request at virtual address ffffff8016df6480
[  240.633388] Unable to handle kernel paging request at virtual address ffffff8016df6480
[  240.633394] Mem abort info:
[  240.633395] Mem abort info:
[  240.633396] Mem abort info:
[  240.633398]   Exception class = DABT (current EL), IL = 32 bits
[  240.633399]   Exception class = DABT (current EL), IL = 32 bits
[  240.633401]   Exception class = DABT (current EL), IL = 32 bits
[  240.633402]   SET = 0, FnV = 0
[  240.633403]   SET = 0, FnV = 0
[  240.633405]   SET = 0, FnV = 0
[  240.633406]   EA = 0, S1PTW = 0
[  240.633407]   EA = 0, S1PTW = 0
[  240.633408]   EA = 0, S1PTW = 0
[  240.633409] Data abort info:
[  240.633409] Data abort info:
[  240.633410] Data abort info:
[  240.633411]   ISV = 0, ISS = 0x00000046
[  240.633412]   ISV = 0, ISS = 0x00000046
[  240.633413]   ISV = 0, ISS = 0x00000046
[  240.633414]   CM = 0, WnR = 1
[  240.633415]   CM = 0, WnR = 1
[  240.633416]   CM = 0, WnR = 1
[  240.633419] swapper pgtable: 4k pages, 39-bit VAs, pgd = ffffff80090b1000
[  240.633421] swapper pgtable: 4k pages, 39-bit VAs, pgd = ffffff80090b1000
[  240.633424] swapper pgtable: 4k pages, 39-bit VAs, pgd = ffffff80090b1000
[  240.633425] [ffffff8016df6480] *pgd=000000097fffe003
[  240.633427] [ffffff8016df6480] *pgd=000000097fffe003
[  240.633429] [ffffff8016df6480] *pgd=000000097fffe003
[  240.633430] , *pud=000000097fffe003
[  240.633431] , *pud=000000097fffe003
[  240.633432] , *pud=000000097fffe003
[  240.633433] , *pmd=0000000000000000
[  240.633434] , *pmd=0000000000000000
[  240.633435] , *pmd=0000000000000000
[  240.792167] Modules linked in:
[  240.795207] CPU: 0 PID: 4831 Comm: cc1plus Not tainted 4.14.0 #10
[  240.801280] Hardware name: xlnx,zynqmp (DT)
[  240.805447] task: ffffffc973db2000 task.stack: ffffff800ef88000
[  240.811355] PC is at calc_global_load+0x1e0/0x1e8
[  240.816039] LR is at do_timer+0x1c/0x28
[  240.819856] pc : [<ffffff80080c2d68>] lr : [<ffffff80080f37c4>] pstate: a00001c5
[  240.827233] sp : ffffff8008003df0
[  240.830531] x29: ffffff8008003df0 x28: ffffffc973db2000 
[  240.835826] x27: ffffffc97ff6dfc0 x26: ffffffc97ff6dfc0 
[  240.841121] x25: ffffffc97ff6dfd0 x24: 0000003803af96c6 
[  240.846416] x23: 0000000000000001 x22: ffffff8008eac000 
[  240.851711] x21: ffffff8008eac000 x20: 0000003803afa045 
[  240.857006] x19: ffffff8008df6000 x18: 0000000000000001 
[  240.862300] x17: 0000007fb5be73b0 x16: 00000000012aec58 
[  240.867595] x15: 0000000000400000 x14: 0000000000007fff 
[  240.872890] x13: 00000000012c9000 x12: 0000007fb0b2e758 
[  240.878185] x11: ffffff8008df6000 x10: 0000000000000040 
[  240.883480] x9 : ffffff8008e0c8e8 x8 : ffffff8008e96000 
[  240.888775] x7 : ffffffc977800268 x6 : 00000000ffffca7b 
[  240.894069] x5 : 00ffffffffffffff x4 : 000000497718f000 
[  240.899364] x3 : 0000003803af7900 x2 : ffffff8008df6000 
[  240.904659] x1 : fffffffffffffb7f x0 : ffffff8008e96ab8 
[  240.909955] Process cc1plus (pid: 4831, stack limit = 0xffffff800ef88000)
[  240.916724] Call trace:
[  240.919157] Exception stack(0xffffff8008003cb0 to 0xffffff8008003df0)
[  240.925580] 3ca0:                                   ffffff8008e96ab8 fffffffffffffb7f
[  240.933393] 3cc0: ffffff8008df6000 0000003803af7900 000000497718f000 00ffffffffffffff
[  240.941205] 3ce0: 00000000ffffca7b ffffffc977800268 ffffff8008e96000 ffffff8008e0c8e8
[  240.949017] 3d00: 0000000000000040 ffffff8008df6000 0000007fb0b2e758 00000000012c9000
[  240.956829] 3d20: 0000000000007fff 0000000000400000 00000000012aec58 0000007fb5be73b0
[  240.964641] 3d40: 0000000000000001 ffffff8008df6000 0000003803afa045 ffffff8008eac000
[  240.972453] 3d60: ffffff8008eac000 0000000000000001 0000003803af96c6 ffffffc97ff6dfd0
[  240.980265] 3d80: ffffffc97ff6dfc0 ffffffc97ff6dfc0 ffffffc973db2000 ffffff8008003df0
[  240.988077] 3da0: ffffff80080f37c4 ffffff8008003df0 ffffff80080c2d68 00000000a00001c5
[  240.995889] 3dc0: 0000000000000040 ffffffc976f6cd20 0000008000000000 ffffff8008003ec0
[  241.003700] 3de0: ffffff8008003df0 ffffff80080c2d68
[  241.008563] [<ffffff80080c2d68>] calc_global_load+0x1e0/0x1e8
[  241.014293] [<ffffff80081000b4>] tick_do_update_jiffies64.part.2+0x6c/0x118
[  241.021236] [<ffffff80081001bc>] tick_sched_do_timer+0x5c/0x68
[  241.027051] [<ffffff8008100248>] tick_sched_timer+0x30/0x90
[  241.032607] [<ffffff80080f0b3c>] __hrtimer_run_queues+0xec/0x168
[  241.038595] [<ffffff80080f0db0>] hrtimer_interrupt+0xa0/0x220
[  241.044327] [<ffffff80087af788>] arch_timer_handler_phys+0x28/0x48
[  241.050489] [<ffffff80080e0798>] handle_percpu_devid_irq+0x80/0x138
[  241.056737] [<ffffff80080dafbc>] generic_handle_irq+0x24/0x38
[  241.062465] [<ffffff80080db66c>] __handle_domain_irq+0x5c/0xb8
[  241.068281] [<ffffff8008081500>] gic_handle_irq+0x68/0xc0
[  241.073661] Exception stack(0xffffff800ef8bec0 to 0xffffff800ef8c000)
[  241.080086] bec0: 00000000000036cf 0000000000000015 0000000000000001 0000000003c71808
[  241.087898] bee0: 0000000003c717f8 0000000000008000 000000000393b8c8 0000000000008000
[  241.095710] bf00: 000000000000006d 0000000000007fff ffffffffffffc000 0000000000000000
[  241.103522] bf20: 0000007fb0b2e758 00000000012c9000 0000000000007fff 0000000000400000
[  241.111334] bf40: 00000000012aec58 0000007fb5be73b0 0000000000000001 0000000000000001
[  241.119146] bf60: 00000000000036ce 00000000039f0820 0000000000000000 0000000003b99de8
[  241.126958] bf80: 0000000000000003 0000000003b9a268 00000000000036ce 00000000012d4000
[  241.134770] bfa0: 0000000000000042 0000007fc21c9290 0000000000798440 0000007fc21c9290
[  241.142582] bfc0: 00000000007983ac 0000000060000000 0000000003c95000 00000000ffffffff
[  241.150394] bfe0: 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000
[  241.158207] [<ffffff8008083614>] el0_irq_naked+0x44/0x4c
[  241.163503] Code: d27a0003 d2800005 1707ffb4 d503201f (d67c03c0) 
[  241.169578] ---[ end trace 8c598a94062fb1cc ]---
[  241.174178] Kernel panic - not syncing: Fatal exception in interrupt
[  241.180514] SMP: stopping secondary CPUs
[  242.251098] SMP: failed to stop secondary CPUs 0-3
[  242.255793] Kernel Offset: disabled
[  242.259266] CPU features: 0x002004
[  242.262650] Memory Limit: none
[  242.265690] ---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: Fatal exception in interrupt
```

Comment: This is either a hardware issue, firmware problem, or kernel bug. If you have support for your system, you definitely need to talk to your vendor(s). This really should not happen.

Comment: Now we confirm using 4G ram(xilinx vivado can config) can solve this problem.
So, this is a gcc bug? or kernel bug?